# Magento 2 - How to display static block based on dropdown selection of created attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, blocks, template

I achieved this funcionality in Magento **1** doing the following:

1. Created an attribute "sizetable" with options "tshirts" and "dresses".
2. Assigned the respective attribute value for each product.
3. Created 2 blocks with identifiers "tshirts" and "dresses".
4. On the product template I added the following code:

`<?php $sizeguide = $_product->getAttributeText('sizetable');
        if ($sizeguide): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeguide)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>`

However this process does not work in Magento **2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your block calling is incorrect, In Magento 2 it should be called as

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($sizeguide)->toHtml()
```

I followed all your steps and added following code to template file, and worked fine.

```
/* $_product = $block->getProduct(); */
$sizeguide = $_product->getAttributeText('sizetable');
if ($sizeguide):
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($sizeguide)->toHtml();
endif;
```

Comment: It works if the first line is uncommented

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct(); 
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sizetable');
if ($attribute)
{
    $sizetable = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($sizeguide)->toHtml();
}
```